# Add class on generated element in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I generate a div when the Checkbox is checked, I can add easily a class with jquery for a div, but i can't add for this generated div.

I need something like this:

```
$('input#edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed').change(function(){
if(this.checked){
     $('#befcontentleft').addClass('green');
}
else {
     //do something else
     $('#befcontentleft').removeClass('green');
}
```

})

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/9UQf8/ but for generated div.

I tried to change .change(function() with .keyup(function(), but doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried giving the generated `<div>` an unique ID, then `$("#the-id-you-just-gave-it").addClass("green")`?

Comment: I'm confused.  This fiddle does not dynamically create a div...  Also you can create a working example on site by hitting `Ctrl+M` while editing, instead of linking to an off-site example.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

try using click instead of change should work

```
$('input#edit-panes-uc-termsofservice-agreement-checkout-tos-agree-agreed').click(function(){


    if(this.checked){
         $('#befcontentleft').addClass('green');
    }else {
     //do something else
         $('#befcontentleft').removeClass('green');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle was just an example, I solved adding the .addClass() to click() function

```
$(function(){
var count = 10,
        $btn = $('.addX'); //Or which ever you want
        //Change the label of $btn
        $btn.val($btn.val()+' ('+count+')')

$btn.click(function(){

        var valCounter = $('#counter').val();

        if (valCounter != 10) {
            valCounter++;
            $('#counter').val(valCounter);
            var n = $( ".section-variation" ).length;
            $( ".counting" ).text( "There are " + n + " Variations");
            //reset 1st variation form

        $(".controlAddx").val("");

    $('.removed').addClass("nascondi");



        } else
  $btn.attr('disabled','disabled');


  if($('#Check1').is(':checked')) {
       $('.removed').addClass('nascondi');
  }
  else {
       //do something else
       $('.removed').removeClass('nascondi');
  }
});
```